# JavaMail cannot find symbol, Uncompilable source

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

I found a tutorial help me to create a mail sender, in the first try is work fine, but after i close netbeans and come again tryin, oups, there is an error, that i can't figure out and netbeans inform that  : `connot find symbol , symbol attachFileString,`

this my Emailer code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

public class Emailer {

    public static void sendEmailWithAttachments(String host, String port,
            final String userName, final String password, String toAddress,
            String subject, String message, String[] attachFiles)
            throws AddressException, MessagingException {
        // sets SMTP server properties
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.user", userName);
        properties.put("mail.password", password);

        // creates a new session with an authenticator
        Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
            public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password);
            }
        };
        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, auth);

        // creates a new e-mail message
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(userName));
        InternetAddress[] toAddresses = { new InternetAddress(toAddress) };
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddresses);
        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());

        // creates message part
        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setContent(message, "text/html");

        // creates multi-part
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        // adds attachments
        if (attachFiles != null && attachFiles.length > 0) {
            for (String filePath : attachFiles) {
                MimeBodyPart attachPart = new MimeBodyPart();

                try {
                    attachPart.attachFile(filePath);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                multipart.addodyPart(attachPart);
            }
        }

        // sets the multi-part as e-mail's content
        msg.setContent(multipart);

        // sends the e-mail
        Transport.send(msg);

    }

}
```

the error is

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - exception java.io.IOException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement
    at Emailer.sendEmailWithAttachments(Emailer.java:63)
```

line 63 (Emailer.java:63) is  :

```
attachPart.attachFile(filePath);
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: You are talking about two errors. The former says that the `try/catch` block is not needed because the method `attachFile()` cannot throw `IOException`.

Comment: if i eliminate try/ catch it give me  this error, java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.attachFile
 at Emailer.sendEmailWithAttachments(Emailer.java:64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be any compilation issue on the line that you indicate. There is a typo here though:

```
multipart.addodyPart(attachPart);
```

It should read

```
multipart.addBodyPart(attachPart);
```

Also, [MimeBodyPart.#attachFile](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#attachFile%28java.io.File%29) was only added in JavaMail 1.4. If you are using an older version, make sure to get *this* version.

Comment: What version of `JDK` are you using and what version of `JavaMail`? I am using `JDK 1.7` with `JM 1.4`.

Comment: i use JDK 7 and JavaMail is included in JDk 7

Comment: Oh cool its okay, a delete and  reload my email library and its goine on again thanks everybody for help

Comment: Note that JavaMail is **not** included in JDK 7, you had to install it separately.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the try catch block surrounding the statement and try to compile it again. As the exception explains, the method you called doesn't throw that exception, and compile errors occur when you attempt to catch non-runtime exceptions that can't happen.

Edit: Or it could be the typo thing.

Comment: if i eliminate try/ catch it give me this error, java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.attachFile at Emailer.sendEmailWithAttachments(Emailer.java:64)

Comment: @Reimeus Oh cool its okay, a delete and  reload my email library and its goine on again thanks everybody for help